# Store quote requests and email if user is inactive

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking to be able to take what is essentially an editorial page for a product and add a "request a quote" button. The user will then need to be prompted for basic info: name, email & phone.

Users can have guest status or be logged in. The client would simply like to be notified via email of the request.

The part I'd appreciate thoughts on, or a pre-boiled plugin for (clients site built in Wordpress, looked but can't see anything), is the best method for preventing the system from sending multiple emails if the user makes multiple quote requests within this session.

The solution should effectively allow the user to only enter their details once -> click as many "request quote" buttons as they like -> then after a certain amount of inactivity, email what they are after to the site owner.

This is the bit I'm stuck on, the best way of sending the users request, without the user actually hitting a 'checkout' type button. I'd really appreciate some thoughts on the best methods to achieve this, which keep it simple for the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save the details in some way I presume. For this answer I'm assuming it's a database, but it really doesn't matter.

When you save `name`, `email` and `phone`, also register a field for the send datetime. This "sendmail_at" is scanned by a process and the mail is send when the time is past.

Every time the user presses a quote button you update the time a bit to give the user time to browse more.

Example:

- 09:00: User requests the first quote. You ask for name/email/phone, and save this togehter with time 10:00 in the database
- 09:10 User browses, sees another thing he likes a quote for, and presses the button. The name/email/phone are still there, but the datetim is updated to 10:10 (and the extra quote id ofcourse)
- etc
- 09:20 Last quote request
- ...
- 10:20 The mailer checks the database and sees that the 'send' time is past, so gathers all the quotes and sends the email.

For mailing: there are 3 parts to this:

1. Periodically calling your function
2. you function for checking if you should mail
3. a mailer function.

The first and last are probably ready made.

- You can use your servers cron-system, or even wordpress's cron system (that on turn can use the servers cronsystem or it's own thing) for this.
- You can probably find a plugin for wordpress, but I'm not sure how you would integrate it, or which one to choose. As you are going to fix point 2. anyway, you might just want to use something like [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

For the middle part you need to write a script that isn't too complicated. You read your database/file/whatever of users, and filter all users that still have to receive a mail, but where the "senddate" is in the past. If you have those email adresses, you compose your mail, and use the function of the mailer I discussed above to actually send the mail.

Tying it all together:

1. Make a script that when given a user, it's email and the quotes, generates an email and sends it (with phpmailer for instance)
2. Make a second script that looks in your database for users to mail, and calls that script
3. Make a cronjob to call that second script every x minutes
4. ....
5. profit!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the mailer process. Is their existing software or scripts designed to run this process?

Comment: Let me add some stuff to the answer